# Search for more than one word in strpos

Tags: php

Is it possible to search for more than one word in `strpos`?

This is what i got:

**PHP**

```
if($a == strpos($a, "aaa")){

//Maby
if($a == strpos($a, "aaa"+"bbb")){
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Maybe another function is more suited.

Comment: I'd suggest to use regex http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: @ChrisLaarman well, it´s a bit complex and iv'e been trying to find out how to solve it. But i need to check for maby 4 words in a string to let the if become true. I will check if you have been on four places.. A, B, C & D. and if you have been on A, you can't go threw B, but the rest. And if you have been on spot B, you can't get passed A. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Downvoter**, can you please comment? Please do check the updated answer!

Simple answer is **No, you can't**. But, you can do this way, **just to check if the `$a` exists in both**:

```
if ($a == (strpos($a, "aaa") && strpos($a, "bbb"))) {
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that the answer to the question is "no". Strpos only returns the first occurrence of the string.

Comment: @Praveen: Ok. This is the only way?

Comment: @DavidBarker Updated the answer. Can you please check?

Comment: @StoneStreet This is the only thing that I am able to think of! May be.

Comment: @StoneStreet Check out this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848002/multiple-search-word-matching-using-strpos